# Erlang/OTP compiler <erlc> not found but required in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, mingw, erlang, ejabberd

I am configuring the ejabberd using Erlang/OTP. When I run ./configure command the Error Occurred.

```
checking for erl... C:\erl5.9\bin
checking for erlc... no
checking for erl... C:\erl5.9\bin
checking for erlc... no
configure : error : Erlang/OTP compiler <erlc> not found but required.
```

I am run the command under MINGW32.

Comment: Have you [downloaded](http://www.erlang.org/download.html) and installed Erlang/OTP?